# Java generics work one time, does not compile second time

Tags: java, generics

this is my accessor method to collection in class AbstractNode:

```
public List<PolygonalChain> getOutEdges() {
    return Collections.unmodifiableList(outEdges);
}
```

but following does not work, compilation error message is:  incompatible types: java.lang.Object cannot be converted to .....FormulaElements.PolygonalChain

```
AbstractNode aNodeExample = getConnectingShape();
for(PolygonalChain outEdge: aNodeExample.getOutEdges()){
    //DO stuff
}
```

What is more confusing to me, is that I can use following code in descendants of AbstractNode without any error:

```
for(PolygonalChain outEdge: getOutEdges()){
    outEdge.delete();
}
```

Here is minimal code, that causes problem:

```
package brokengenerics;

import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.util.List;


public class BrokenGenerics {
public static abstract class AClass <E extends Number> {
    private List<B> bs;

    public List<B> getBs(){
        return bs;
    }

}
public static class B extends AClass<BigInteger>{

}

public static AClass getSomething(){
    return new B();
}
/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {

    for(B desc : getSomething().getBs())){

}
}

}
```

Comment: Could you provide `AbstractNode` and `FormulaElements` classes bodies?

Comment: can you cast aNodeExample.getOutEdges() ? `(List<PolygonalChain>)aNodeExample.getOutEdges()`

Comment: FormulaElements is package. Declaration of PolygonalChain is:
`public class PolygonalChain extends AbstractNode<Line>{ ...}`.

So I am using descendant in ancestor, is it what causes problem?

Comment: erencan: yes, I can cast whole list and also containing objects like: `for(Object outEdge1: aNode.getOutEdges()){
    PolygonalChain outEdge = (PolygonalChain) outEdge1;}` without any problem

Comment: Is there another more general definition of getOutEdges() somewhere in your program? edit: Also, you probably want to return a "List<? extends PolygonalChain>", that way subtypes are allowed to override it and return a "List<? extends SomeSubclassOfPolygonalChain>"

Comment: Score_Under: No, AbstractNode is my topmost class in this hierarchy and it is only place where getOutEdges is defined.

Comment: So, I moved foreach loop as method into AbstractNode, which seemed to be cleanest solution, other than manually casting. But I am still curious what causes this behavior.

Comment: all things being equal (all the code is in one project, single version of Java 1.5+ etc), perhaps a clean build may help (Eclipse: Project - Clean...)

Comment: I experimented a bit and found that you won't get the error if aNodeExample is declared as an AbstractNode<Line> instead of an AbstractNode.

Comment: nitegazer2003: interesting, but I don't know what specific class was used in generic type. It might have been any allowed. 

For those who are interested, here here is minimal implementation that causes problem: http://paste.ofcode.org/JRUgjkMru3adC5fjbnPBKp

Comment: I think all this is because of the type erasure in the Java generics: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html. Check the section "Effects of Type Erasure and Bridge Methods".

Comment: In your minimal example the problem is that AClass is generic but you are declaring the static `getSomething` method returns the raw type `AClass` - change it to return `AClass<BigInteger>` and the problem goes away.